# call web service to populate data in form oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

i have  a page look like a form , and  i have a web service  to get customer data from other database ,

in my  page i have ID (item) ,  how i can get all data related to value in (ID) item and set this value in others item (address , birth date ...... )  by web service .

how i can call web service by dynamic action when (when change ), please any advise ?

Comment: What version of APEX are you using? How are you using the API to get the customer data? Does the API support updating customer data?

Comment: Apex 19.2 , call using apex_web_service.make_rest_request , no i don't need update data only i want fiil form and add some extra data in form  and save data in database

Comment: So, you want to populate a form using a REST API based on the ID value. Then you want to store the data in your local database. Is that right? Why are you trying to call the web service via a dynamic action (rather than say a page load process)? Does the REST API require authentication?

Comment: Yes, i using dynamic action because the main goal of this page (search page) when the resident come to hospital i want get all data and fill missing information add some other information  ,  yes required authentication

Comment: I see. So the page would load, they would put in some of their info, and then you would fetch the rest, right? I hope this is for use by doctors and not patients, as there may be some security/privacy issues otherwise.

Comment: Yes the doctor only have access.

Comment: The solution I think may be right for you (in a general sense) is to create a dynamic action that listens for the `change` event on various form items or the `click` of a "lookup" button. The action would be: Execute PL/SQL. Items to Submit would be the ID item and Items to Return would be the items that you want to set. Then, the PL/SQL code would make the REST call and use the result to set the session state of the items in the Items to Return field.

Comment: Let me know if that's enough, of if you'd like me to provide a step by step example (likely based on the sample REST API included with APEX).

Comment: Thanks, Ok I will try that.